# MysQl error : Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error :

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /FondManager.class.php on line 69
```

When trying to execute this :

```
$Fond_Modif = $Manager->get($id);
$Fond_Modif->setContactname($_POST['name']);
$Manager->update($Fond_Modif);
```

Here is the concerned class :

```
 public function update(Fond $Fond)
  {
    $q = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE fonds SET Name, ContactName, ContactPosition, ContactMail, ContactPhone, Website, MinTic, MaxTic WHERE id = :id');

    $q->bindValue(':id', $Fond->id());
    $q->bindValue(':name', $Fond->name(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':contactname', $Fond->contactname(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':contactposition', $Fond->contactposition(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':contactmail', $Fond->contactmail(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':contactphone', $Fond->contactphone(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':website', $Fond->website(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':mintic', $Fond->mintic(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(':maxtic', $Fond->maxtic(), PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $q->execute();
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to "mention" all placeholders in your query

```
$q = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE fonds 
                          SET Name = :name,
                          ContactName = :contactname,  
                          ContactPosition = :contactposition, 
                          ContactMail = :contactmail,
                          ContactPhone = :contactphone, 
                          Website = :website
                          MinTic = :mintic, 
                          MaxTic = :maxtic
                          WHERE id = :id");
```

PDO replaces only placeholders. You have to add that placeholders to your query.

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MinTic = '2', MaxTic = '500' ' at line 8 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/JG/FondManager.class.php on line 79
 Copied your code, now I'm getting this error :)

Comment: They are not in your query. Only the column names. And you are missing the `=` too

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was forgetting some commas !